# SQL Server Express 2005: How to import fixed width data using BCP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, import, bcp

I’m trying to import fixed width data from text file into SQL Server Express using BCP. I have read some Microsoft’s web pages about this matter, but I haven’t got far with them. Can please give some examples or point to some good tutorials about this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a wealth of material out there, and these two articles seem like a good start:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/An-Introduction-To-The-Bulk-Copy-Utility/

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=319