# Reading and aggregating thousands of files using C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql

I have a lot of files lying out on random file shares. I have to copy them into my SQL Server 2008 database and sum up all of the points. The overhead to copying the file from the network to C# to database makes this process slow and I have thousands of very large files to process.

File 1 example

```
Player | Points
---------------
Bean   | 10
Ender  | 15
```

File 2 example

```
Player | Points
---------------
Ender  | 20
Peter  | 5
```

Result

```
Player | Points
---------------
Bean   | 10
Ender  | 35
Peter  | 5
```

Current approach: using C#, read each file into the database and merge into the master table.

```
MERGE INTO Points as Target
USING Source as Source
 ON Target.Player = Source.Player
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Target.Points = Target.Points + Source.Points
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (Player, Points) VALUES (Source.Player, Source.Points);
```

This approach is fine, but I'm looking ideas for improvement (kinda slow).

Proposed solution:

Read each file into a SQLite database (based on reading, this should be very fast), bulk load the entire database into my SQL Server database and do all of the processing there. I should be able to assign a rank to each player, thus speeding up the grouping since I'm not comparing based on a text column. Downfall of proposed solution is it can't work on multiple threads.

**What's the fastest way to get all of these files into the database and them aggregate them?**

**Edit:** A little more background on the files I forgot to mention

- These files are located on several servers
- I need to keep the "impact" of this task to a minimum - so no installing of apps
- The files can be *huge* - as much as 1gb per file, so doing anything in memory is not an option
- There are thousands of files to process

Comment: Gee this sounds like a architectural DailyWTF... huge text files across multiple webserver's :(  fyi: I have done a similar thing successfully with [SQL BCP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371022/sql-server-express-2005-how-to-import-fixed-width-data-using-bcp) but the files weren't scattered across servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you can't/don't want to run code to start the parsing operation on the individual servers containing these files, and transferring the gigs and gigs of them is slow, then whether this is multithreaded is probably irrelevant - the performance bottleneck in your process is the file transfer.

So to make some assumptions:

1. There's the one master server and only it does any work.
2. It has immediate (if slow) access to all the file shares necessary, accessible by a simple path, and you know those paths.
3. The master tally server has a local database sitting on it to store player scores.

If you can transfer multiple files just as fast as you can transfer one, I'd write code that did the following:

1. Gather the list of files that needs to be aggregated - this at least should be a small and cheap list. Gather them into a [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx).
2. Spin up as many Tasks as the bandwidth on the machine will allow you to run copy operations. You'll need to test to determine what this is.
3. Each Task takes the ConcurrentBag as an argument. It begins with a loop running TryTake() until it succeeds - once it's successfully removed a filepath from the bag it begins reading directly from the file location and parsing, adding each user's score to whatever is currently in the local database for that user.
4. Once a Task finishes working on a file it resumes trying to get the next filepath from the ConcurrentBag and so forth.
5. Eventually all filepaths have been worked on and the Tasks end.

So the code would be roughly:

```
public void Start()
{
    var bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    for(var i = 0; i < COPY_OPERATIONS; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            StartCopy(bag);
        });
    }
}

public void StartCopy(ConcurrentBag<string> bag)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Loop until the bag is available to hand us a path to work on
        string path = null;
        while (!bag.IsEmpty && !bag.TryTake(out path))
        {}

        // Access the file via a stream and begin parsing it, dumping scores to the db
    }
}
```

By streaming you keep the copy operations running full tilt (in fact most likely the OS will readahead a bit for you to really ensure you max out the copy speed) and still avoid knocking over memory with the size of these files.

By not using multiple intermediary steps you skip the repeated cost of transferring and considering all that data - this way you do it just the once.

And by using the above approach you can easily account for the optimal number of copy operations.

There are optimizations you can make here to make it easily restartable like having all threads receive a signal to stop what they're doing and record in the database the files they've worked on, the one they were working on now, and the line they left off on. You could have them constantly write these values to the database at a small cost to performance to make it crash proof (by making the line number and score writes part of a single transaction).

---

### Original answer

You forgot to specify this in your question but it appears these scattered files log the points scored by players playing a game on a cluster of webservers?

This sounds like an embarrassingly parallel problem. Instead of copying massive files off of each machine, why not write a simple app that can run on all of them and distribute it to them? It just sums the points there on the machine and sends back a single number and player id per player over the network, solving the slow network issue.

If this is an on-going task you can timestamp the sums so you never count the same point twice and just run it in batch periodically.

I'd write the webserver apps as a simple webapp that only responds to one IP (the master tally server you were originally going to do everything on), and in response to a request, runs the tally locally and responds with the sum. That way the master server just sends requests out to all the score servers, and waits for them to send back their sums. Done.

You can keep the client apps very simple by just storing the sum data in memory as a Dictionary mapping player id to sum - no SQL necessary.

The tally software can also likely do everything in RAM then dump it all to SQL Server as totals complete to save time.

Fun problem.

Comment: The log files contain only the information I posted above and are scattered across multiple servers as you guessed. I can't run apps on the servers. I can't do it in memory because these files are HUGE (they don't actually contain player/point info) and, as noted above, there are thousands of them

Comment: Ah but you can. You stream the files and only keep in memory the much smaller player/point data. Unless the number of players itself is also very massive - but even then you can stream that data out if players are specified sequentially.